# How to compare performance of different supercapacitors

Tags: capacitance

I've been reading a research review paper about supercapacitors (SC)

http://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlehtml/2015/ee/c4ee03229b

I want to compare the performance of SCs based on their capacitance. But what I see in this review paper is different units. Sometimes they're talking about areal capacitance so they say 890 F/cm^2, sometimes volumetric with unit F/cm^3 and sometimes gravimetric with unit F/g.

My question is- Is there any way to compare the different SCs in spite of the differences in the units? Is there a rule of thumb?

P.S. It mostly deals with porous materials as electrodes so I don't understand why they need to measure capacitance per unit mass. Isn't capacitance per unit volume more important?

Answer (score 0):

the most common way to compare between supercapacitors is to measure the specific capacitance which is F/g. but to say this is not the way for comparing cuz when you build the final device the most important to measure is energy density and power density which is related to specific capacitance directly E=1/2 C V^2 where C is the specific capacitance of electrode material. so when you are testing the mass loading of the material on the electrode would affect the capacitance that you calculate of CV testing that when you are worried about the mass loading then you have gravimetric capacitance, but actually when we are talking about building the final device which could be a coin cell for example or any type of supercapacitors devices then you could face the volumetric capacitance which i think it's the practical way, so for you you gotta have the same units if you are going to compare.